# Implementing OpenSearch, what is the benefits?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engines, google-search, search, site-search

I have implemented opensearch in my website. But I don't know what is the benefits of it. Does it has any effects in search engines? For example, can I tell google about my implementation?

Comment: why would implement this without researching...

Comment: Well, my website has a powerful search system, to implement OS I had to create a XML output for search system and it was actually easy and I did it quickly. So, has it any benefits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSearch has no bearing on search engine rankings. OpenSearch allows users to add your search engine to their browser.

To quote wikipedia:

> “OpenSearch is a collection of technologies that allow publishing of search results in a format suitable for syndication and aggregation. It is a way for websites and search engines to publish search results in a standard and accessible format.”

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSearch